# parallel computing for glmulti in R in Windows

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing, glmulti

as per [glmulti package document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmulti/glmulti.pdf), chunks are arguments for using multi CPUs.

when using exhaustive screening.

But, even when I put 4 in both chunk and chunks and method='h' with family='binomial', R only use a single core.

the function I used

`glmulti(y~. ,level=1,data=ctrain,fitfunction = 'glm',chunk = 4, chunks = 4,method = 'h',family='binomial')`

demo data set that is similar to mine:- https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00222/bank-additional.zip

PS: any other the package that solve problem is also acceptable.

Comment: Which function are you using? Also can you provide some data and the complete function call you tried.

Comment: @F.Privé I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the vignette (that you can download [there](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjb1KLJrYzWAhVEZFAKHeT4A48QFghDMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Farticle%2Fview%2Fv034i12%2Fv34i12.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFydCkFuk3k7ip3Fp0iQAvUGYWzyQ)), you see that `chunk` is determining only one part of the computation.

I think you just need to make calls from a loop with `chunk in seq_len(chunks)` and combine the results.

You should email the author or open an issue for further information.

Comment: can you please elaborate - I also updated the question to give you details.

Comment: Now I understand chunk part, But don't know how to utilise.

Comment: You should email the author or open an issue for further information.